# this.state.foodReducer is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

**FoodList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { Content, List, ListItem } from "native-base";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { deleteFood } from "../../redux/actions/food";

const FoodList = () => {    
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const deleteCurrent = (key) => dispatch(deleteFood(key));
  const foods = useSelector((state) => state.foodReducer.FoodList);  <------------

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={foods}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key.toString()}
      renderItem={(data) => <ListItem title={data.item.name} />}
    />
  );
};

export default FoodList;
```

**FoodCreate.js**

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addFood } from "../../redux/actions/food";

const FoodCreate = ({ navigation: { goBack } }) => {
  const [food, setFood] = useState("");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const submitFood = (food) => dispatch(addFodd(food));


  return (
    <Container>
      <Header>
        <Left>
          <Button transparent>
            <Icon
              name="arrow-back"
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
              style={{ fontSize: 25, color: "red" }}
            />
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Title>Add Food</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right>
          <Button transparent>
            <Icon
              name="checkmark"
              style={{ fontSize: 25, color: "red" }}
              onPress={() => {
                submitFood(food);
                setFood("");
              }}
            />
          </Button>
        </Right>
      </Header>
      <View style={{ alignItems: "center", top: hp("3%") }}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Food Name"
          placeholderTextColor="white"
          style={styles.inptFood}
          value={food}
          onChangeText={(food) => setFood(food)}
        />
      </View>
```

**actions/food.js**

```
import { ADD_FOOD, DELETE_FOOD } from "./types";

export const addFood = (food) => ({
  type: ADD_FOOD,
  data: food,
});

export const deleteFood = (key) => ({
  type: DELETE_FOOD,
  key: key,
});
```

**store/store.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import foodReducer from "../reducers/foodReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  foodReducer: foodReducer,
});

const configureStore = () => createStore(rootReducer);

export default configureStore;
```

**actions/types.js**

```
export const ADD_FOOD = "ADD_FOOD";
export const DELETE_FOOD = "DELETE_FOOD";
```

**reducers/foodReducer.js**

```
import { ADD_FOOD, DELETE_FOOD } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  FoodList: [],
};

const foodReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_FOOD:
      return {
        ...state,
        FoodList: state.FoodList.concat({
          key: Math.random(),
          name: action.data,
        }),
      };
    case DELETE_FOOD:
      return {
        ...state,
        FoodList: state.FoodList.filter((item) => item.key != action.key),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default foodReducer;
```

**App.js**

```
import FoodListScreen from "./components/Main/FoodList.js";
import configureStore from "./redux/store/store";
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const store =
  (createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk)), configureStore());

return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="FoodCreate"
              component={FoodCreateScreen}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="FoodList"
              component={FoodListScreen}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
```

Hey everyone, I'm new to redux and I'm trying to use it my Diet App, the user creates a Food item in FoodCreate.js and it will be listed in FoodList.js, at the moment when I run the code it gives me back the following error: `state.foodReducer.FoodList is undefined`, I put an arrow next to the line of code that gives me the error, I used this approach by following the following YouTube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTJ6zo5GO7E, thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

ok maybe i found

```
//In your store/store.js

import { createStore, combineReducers,applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import foodReducer from "../reducers/foodReducer";

const configureStore = () => {
 const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    foodReducer: foodReducer,
  }),
  applyMiddleware(thunk)

);

  return store;
}

export default configureStore;


//In your App.js
...

import configureStore from "./redux/store/store";
const store = ConfigureStore();

return(
  <Provider store={store}>
      ...
  </Provider>
)
```

Comment: Yes I did, the exact way you posted

Comment: oki what do you have if you debug
const foods = useSelector((state) => state);

console.log(foods)

Comment: it gives nothing back, I run it and it just keeps showing the same error

Comment: in your App.js you miss the import thunk from "redux-thunk" and the import { applyMiddleware } from "redux"